# How to use output from find for if-condition?

Tags: linux, bash

I would like that if this command outputs anything

```
find /var/www/cgi-bin -name touch -cmin 10
```

then should "ok" be echoed.

Have tried

```
if [ $(find /var/www/cgi-bin -name touch -cmin 10) ]; then echo "ok";fi
```

but it never echoes anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even better you can do it like this:

```
find /var/www/cgi-bin -name touch -cmin 10 -exec echo "ok" \;
```

HTH

Answer (score 3):

Put double quotes around `$(..)`:

```
if [ "$(find /var/www/cgi-bin -name touch -cmin 10)" ]; then echo "ok"; fi
```

This will interpret the output of `find` as a single word.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you

if [ -n "$(find ./var/www/cgi-bin -name touch -cmin 10)" ];then echo ok;fi

Comment: Use `-mindepth 1` to avoid print the directory itself. 

Answer (score 1):

```
if find ... | grep . > /dev/null; then
  echo found something
fi
```

If you need the output:

```
if h=$(find ... | grep . ); then
  echo found $h
fi
```